# Ask book to deeply understand partially ordered sets

Tags: reference-request, order-theory

I learn little about ordering and poset before, but I think it's not enough and want to learn more about ordering and Poset. Can anyone please recommend some best books to learn about this topic. I really appreciate it. Thanks so much

Comment: I cannot say much about this book other than I found it by looking at the references on the wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#References 
The link on google books is Here: http://books.google.com/books/about/Ordered_sets.html?id=2esoXnolEWgC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E.Harzheim, Ordered Sets, Springer Verlag, 2005.